# How to import compressed .csv file from AWS-EFS to MariaDB Cluster

Tags: csv, import, compression, mariadb, amazon-efs

We copy compressed .csv files from AWS-S3 (U.S.) to AWS-EFS (Europe) and need to import them into MariaDB Cluster (Europe), challenge is where/how to best do decompression when calling mySQLImport or LOAD DATA INFILE.

Background:

Users (via browser-based client) will upload large .csv files (<=2GB) using a pre-signed URL to AWS-S3, to then be imported into our European MariaDB cluster.  We copy the compressed files from S3 to AWS-EFS (Europe).  We use EFS  because of speed (over S3) and we don't know what load-balanced DB server will handle the LOAD DATA INFILE (EBS is EC2-specific, so not fault-tolerant).

Our SysAdmin is recommending to write a bash script to decompress the file using one of the DB servers in the cluster, then do the import using mySqlImport of LOAD DATA INFILE.  The concern is that we'd be slowing down the DB server(s) for a decompression task that's not normally done by a DB server (I/O, CPU, Memory impact affecting online users).

We can't decompress in the U.S. and ship the file decompressed to AWS Europe region, because of higher transfer times and inter-region transfer costs.

Question:

Is the solution to add a single or dual servers near the DB Cluster to handle decompression (need to have failover, loadbalancing, etc. to be robust) or is using the DB server for decompression ok, maybe 'beefing up' the db servers will suffice ?  ...or any other options ?

Answer (score 0):

*If* AWS even lets you do `LOAD DATA`, then

1. Compress the csv file in US.
2. Ship the compressed file to Europe.
3. Decompress the file in Europe.
4. Run `LOAD DATA INPUT`.

Note:  Steps 1,2,3 do not involve the database.  Even if you are using the same VM for the work, the impact on the database should be minimal (chewing up IOPs).

A typical CSV file compresses only 3:1.  Is it worth the effort to save only 1.3GB of xfer costs for a 2GB file?

Comment: "Decompress in Europe", yes, agree, makes sense.  However, where?  Note, this is a multi-user SaaS app, so many users could be running uploads.  We'd need a minicluster for availability reasons, so we can decompress before LOAD DATA INFILE ?  It sounds like it or we may need to do the math as to what's more costly... (A) transferring unencrypted, no decompression servers, but ending up with higher transfer cost and longer transfer times  vs.  (B) compressing, saving transfer cost, but extra servers for decompressing.

Comment: @JohnDoe999 - I have trouble imagining that the decompression will require extra servers.  MySQL servers usually have lots of CPU cores sitting idle.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback !